# regarding different types of pattern class pattern and object pattern

Tags: design-patterns

I am new to design pattern and donot have much experience in it .I am confused with object pattern and class .one difference i noticed is class pattern uses inheritence and object pattern uses composition.I am working on c++ ,so let me know c++ support object/class pattern ,SInce in the Book GOF ,there is not having clear explanation .

my question is why class pattern and object pattern is used and when and where it is used .As i am very new to this .please let me know in simple ,with example.

Thanks all gurus

Comment: The only way to learn design patterns is to have a problem solvable with a design pattern. At this point it doesn't matter. Just try to solve the problems as best as you can. You will understand them in time.

Answer (score 0):

Design patterns can be classified in different categories. 
As the number of pattern grows it's necessary try to organize them into several subsets.

Exists different criteria to form these subsets of patterns, for example, 
you can find patterns that were grouped according his **purpose**, forming the following categories: Creational, Behavioral and Structural.

`Class pattern` and `Object pattern`, are just other kind of categories where patterns were grouped following other criteria: the kind of relationship they follow.

> i noticed class pattern uses inheritence and object pattern uses composition.

yes; relationships in `Class patterns` are established at compile time. (the kind of relationship formed by inheritance) 
 whereas relationships in `Object patterns` are established at runtimetime (the kind of relationships formed by composition)

You can find other patterns categories, however, if you are starting to study patterns don't worry about this stuff.

In [this](http://books.google.com.uy/books/about/Head_First_Design_Patterns.html?id=LjJcCnNf92kC&redir_esc=y) good book you can find (in the final chapter) a good explanation about patterns categories. Notice the fact that this topic
was at the end of the book :)

good luck with your patterns study.